# GET request with a dot inside

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, restsharp

I create a web service RESTful, know i want to use one service from this webservice, with the RestSharp API

Works:

```
http://localhost:7895/.../Connexion/login/pass
```

If i put a breakpoint in the service, the service is called, and everything works great

Don't works:

```
http://localhost:7895/.../Connexion/lo.gin/pass
```

If a put a breakpoint in the service, the service is never called.

**EDIT**
Here the url, if you want the exact url

```
http://192.168.56.1:1759/ConnexionService.svc/Connexion/jean.marc/HASHEDPASSWORD";
```

That works

```
http://192.168.56.1:1759/ConnexionService.svc/Connexion/jeanmarc/HASHEDPASSWORD";
```

jean.marc is the login.
Then i generate a oauth signature, wich is added to the url
Then I use the RestSharp API to do the request.

The problem is, when a do a request with the login jean.marc, my service is never called.
The dot, are there because the login is constructed with the first name "dot" the last name.
If it's not possible to pass information with dot, i should change the login structure and just add an underscore.

Comment: We can't really see those link that refer to YOUR localhost, you know...

Comment: Are you trying to accommodate erroneous periods? Or do you need it to be present?

Comment: Please use your global ip address, so that we can see the address

Comment: Have you tried to escape dot? Are you sure need to support dot?

Comment: @abatishchev I meant use global ip address instead of localhost in the URL which you usually provide......This will enable us to see your webpage and will try to give answer..:)

Comment: just edited to be more explicit

Comment: When do you say service is never called, do you actually see any error on client side? or it just silently dies?

Comment: the service is silently die, there are no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the second one doesn't work; it's a different URL.

You can't just throw dots in wherever and expect it to work.  Why do you want to add extra dots?

Comment: So, it's normal that the webservice is never called if a had a dot in one parameter?

Comment: My bet would be the server is matching URLs ("routing") with a regular expression that doesn't match periods in the username.  Is this your server or are you using a third-party service?